# Python buffered IO ending early streaming with multiple pipes

Tags: python, ffmpeg, pipe, buffer, youtube-dl

I'm trying to make a continuous livestream of videos downloaded via yt-dlp. I need to port this (working) bash command into Python.

```
(
    youtube-dl -v --buffer-size 16k https://youtube.com/watch?v=QiInzFHIDp4 -o - | ffmpeg -i - -f mpegts -c copy - ;
    youtube-dl -v --buffer-size 16k https://youtube.com/watch?v=QiInzFHIDp4 -o - | ffmpeg -i - -f mpegts -c copy - ;
) | ffmpeg -re -i - -c:v libx264 -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1/live/H1P_x5WPF
```

My Python attempt is cutting off the last ~2 seconds of each video. My suspicion is that although the first pipe, yt-dlp, has an empty stdout, there is still data travelling between the second and third pipe. I haven't been able to figure out a way to properly handle the data between those two pipes at the end of the video.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, DEVNULL

COPY_BUFSIZE = 65424

playlist = [
    {
        # 15 second video
        "url": "https://youtube.com/watch?v=QiInzFHIDp4"
    },
    {
        # 15 second video
        "url": "https://youtube.com/watch?v=QiInzFHIDp4"
    },
    {
        # 15 second video
        "url": "https://youtube.com/watch?v=QiInzFHIDp4"
    },
]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    stream_cmd = [
        "ffmpeg", "-loglevel", "error",
        "-hide_banner", "-re", "-i", "-",
        "-c:v", "libx264",
        "-f", "flv",
        "-b:v", "3000k", "-minrate", "3000k",
        "-maxrate", "3000k", "-bufsize", "3000k",
        "-r", "25", "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p",
        "rtmp://127.0.0.1/live/H1P_x5WPF"
    ]
    print(f'Stream command:\n"{" ".join(stream_cmd)}"')

    encoder_cmd = [
        "ffmpeg", "-re", "-i", "-", "-f", "mpegts",
        "-c", "copy", "-"
    ]
    print(f'Encoder command:\n"{" ".join(encoder_cmd)}"')

    stream_p = Popen(stream_cmd, stdin=PIPE, stderr=DEVNULL)

    for video in playlist:
        yt_dlp_cmd = [
            "yt-dlp", "-q",
            video["url"],
            "-o", "-"
        ]

        print("Now playing: " + video["url"])

        with Popen(yt_dlp_cmd, stdout=PIPE) as yt_dlp_p:
            with Popen(encoder_cmd, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=DEVNULL) as encoder_p:
                while True:
                    yt_dlp_buf = yt_dlp_p.stdout.read(COPY_BUFSIZE)
                    print("READ: yt_dlp")
                    if not yt_dlp_buf:
                        print("yt-dlp buffer empty")
                        # Handle any data in 2nd/3rd pipes before breaking?
                        break

                    written = encoder_p.stdin.write(yt_dlp_buf)
                    print("WRITE: encoder. Bytes: " + str(written))

                    encoder_buf = encoder_p.stdout.read(COPY_BUFSIZE)
                    # if not encoder_buf:
                    #     print("encoder_buf empty")
                    #     break
                    print("READ: encoder")

                    stream_bytes_written = stream_p.stdin.write(encoder_buf)
                    print("WRITE: stream, Bytes: " + str(stream_bytes_written))
```

Running Python 3.6.9 on MacOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closing the `stdin` pipe is required for "pushing" the sub-process remaining (buffered) data to `stdout` pipe.

For example, add `encoder_p.stdin.close()` after finish writing all data to `encoder_p.stdin`.

---

I don't understand how your code is working.
In my machine, it gets stack at `encoder_buf = encoder_p.stdout.read(COPY_BUFSIZE)`.

I solved the problem using a "writer thread".
The "writer thread" reads data from `yt_dlp_p` and write it to `encoder_p.stdin`.

Note: In your specific case, it could work without a thread (because the data is just passed through FFmpeg, and not being encoded), but usually, the encoded data is not ready right after writing the input to FFmpeg.

---

My code sample uses FFplay sub-process for playing the video (we need the video player because the RTMP streaming requires a "listener" in order to keep streaming).

---

Here is a complete code sample:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, DEVNULL
import threading
import time

COPY_BUFSIZE = 65424

playlist = [
    {
        # 15 second video
        "url": "https://youtube.com/watch?v=QiInzFHIDp4"
    },
    {
        # 15 second video
        "url": "https://youtube.com/watch?v=QiInzFHIDp4"
    },
    {
        # 15 second video
        "url": "https://youtube.com/watch?v=QiInzFHIDp4"
    },
]



# Writer thread (read from yt-dlp and write to FFmpeg in chunks of COPY_BUFSIZE bytes).
def writer(yt_dlp_proc, encoder_proc):
    while True:
        yt_dlp_buf = yt_dlp_proc.stdout.read(COPY_BUFSIZE)
        print("READ: yt_dlp")
        if not yt_dlp_buf:
            print("yt-dlp buffer empty")
            break

        written = encoder_proc.stdin.write(yt_dlp_buf)
        print("WRITE: encoder. Bytes: " + str(written))
    
    encoder_proc.stdin.close()  # Close stdin pipe (closing stdin "pushes" the remaining data to stdout).
    encoder_proc.wait()  # Wait for sub-process finish execution.


if __name__ == "__main__":
    rtmp_url = "rtmp://127.0.0.1/live/H1P_x5WPF"

    ffplay_cmd = ['ffplay', '-listen', '1', '-i', rtmp_url] # Start the TCP server first, before the sending client.    
    ffplay_process = Popen(ffplay_cmd, stderr=DEVNULL)  # Use FFplay sub-process for receiving the RTMP video.

    stream_cmd = [
        "ffmpeg", "-loglevel", "error",
        "-hide_banner", "-re", "-i", "-",
        "-c:v", "libx264",
        "-f", "flv",
        "-b:v", "3000k", "-minrate", "3000k",
        "-maxrate", "3000k", "-bufsize", "3000k",
        "-r", "25", "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p",
        rtmp_url #"rtmp://127.0.0.1/live/H1P_x5WPF"
    ]
    print(f'Stream command:\n"{" ".join(stream_cmd)}"')

    encoder_cmd = [
        "ffmpeg", "-re", "-i", "-", "-f", "mpegts",
        "-c", "copy", "-"
    ]
    print(f'Encoder command:\n"{" ".join(encoder_cmd)}"')

    stream_p = Popen(stream_cmd, stdin=PIPE, stderr=DEVNULL)

    for video in playlist:
        yt_dlp_cmd = [
            "yt-dlp", "-q",
            video["url"],
            "-o", "-"
        ]

        print("Now playing: " + video["url"])

        with Popen(yt_dlp_cmd, stdout=PIPE) as yt_dlp_p:
            with Popen(encoder_cmd, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=DEVNULL) as encoder_p:

                thread = threading.Thread(target=writer, args=(yt_dlp_p, encoder_p))
                thread.start()  # Start writer thread.

                while True:
                    encoder_buf = encoder_p.stdout.read(COPY_BUFSIZE)

                    if not encoder_buf:
                        print("encoder_buf empty")
                        break

                    print("READ: encoder")

                    stream_bytes_written = stream_p.stdin.write(encoder_buf)
                    print("WRITE: stream, Bytes: " + str(stream_bytes_written))

        thread.join()  # Wait for writer thread to end.
        yt_dlp_p.wait()

    stream_p.stdin.close()  # Close stdin pipe (closing stdin "pushes" the remaining data to stdout).
    stream_p.wait()  # Wait for sub-process finish execution.


    time.sleep(3)  # Wait 3 seconds before closing FFplay
    ffplay_process.kill()  # Forcefully close FFplay sub-process
```

---

### Update:

I found a simpler solution using [pytube](https://pytube.io/en/latest/) and [concat filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat) (without pipes).

I don't know if the solution is relevant for you...

Code sample:

```
from pytube import YouTube
from subprocess import Popen, run, PIPE, DEVNULL
import time

playlist = [
    {
        # 15 second video
        "url": "https://youtube.com/watch?v=QiInzFHIDp4"
    },
    {
        # 15 second video
        "url": "https://youtube.com/watch?v=QiInzFHIDp4"
    },
    {
        # 15 second video
        "url": "https://youtube.com/watch?v=QiInzFHIDp4"
    },
]

n = len(playlist)

# Build string for concat demuxer https://video.stackexchange.com/a/18256/18277
filter_complex_str = ''
for i in range(n):
    filter_complex_str += f'[{i}:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v{i}];[{i}:a]asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a{i}];'   # "[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0];[0:a]asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a0];[1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1];[1:a]asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a1];[2:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v2];[2:a]asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a2]"
for i in range(n):
    filter_complex_str += f'[v{i}][a{i}]'  # ";[v0][a0][v1][a1][v2][a2]"
filter_complex_str += f'concat=n={n}:v=1:a=1[v][a]'

# Get the video stream URL of every YouTube HTTP URL.
# Add -i before each URL (to be used as FFmpeg input).
playlist_url = []
for video in playlist:
    yt = YouTube(video["url"])
    # https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues/301
    stream_url = yt.streams[0].url  # Get the URL of the video stream
    playlist_url.append('-i')
    playlist_url.append(stream_url)


rtmp_url = "rtmp://127.0.0.1/live/H1P_x5WPF"

ffplay_cmd = ['ffplay', '-listen', '1', '-i', rtmp_url]  # Start the TCP server first, before the sending client.
ffplay_process = Popen(ffplay_cmd, stderr=DEVNULL)  # Use FFplay sub-process for receiving the RTMP video.

stream_cmd = [
    "ffmpeg", "-loglevel", "error",
    "-hide_banner", "-re"] + playlist_url + ["-filter_complex",
    filter_complex_str,  # '[0:v][0:a][1:v][1:a][2:v][2:a]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[v][a]'
    "-map", "[v]", "-map", "[a]",
    "-c:v", "libx264",
    "-f", "flv",
    "-b:v", "3000k", "-minrate", "3000k",
    "-maxrate", "3000k", "-bufsize", "3000k",
    "-r", "25", "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p",
    rtmp_url]

run(stream_cmd)

time.sleep(60)  # Wait 60 seconds before closing FFplay
ffplay_process.kill()  # Forcefully close FFplay sub-process
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'll definitely consider the bounty complete.  I was unaware of the requirement to close the middle pipe to push the data through.
One thing i'm noticing is that now the stream will consistently delay when the video hits 2 seconds remaining starting on the second video onward. The first video plays perfectly though. If you add some more of the 15 second videos to your playlist, does the same thing happen to you?
I'm going to mess with settings and learn more about the threading to see if I can figure it out.

Comment: I am not interested getting payed... Regarding the latency, try to set '-probesize 32'.

Comment: Probesize change didn't fix it. I noticed the ffmpeg stream process was outputting `[mpegts @ 0x7fc6aa00e400] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 1608000)`. This happens around the time when the yt-dlp and ffmpeg copy processes are replaced. I fixed it by adding `-fflags discardcorrupt` to the ffmpeg stream. I still get the Packet Corrupt warning and now additionally receive a `[libmp3lame @ 0x7faca7008e00] Queue input is backward in time` and `[flv @ 0x7faca6024200] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream`, but it all seems to work now!

Comment: I have tried few modifications, but every change chausses different problem. If you don't need audio, I think possible solution is decoding the input into raw video frames (NumPy arrays in RGB format) and writing the raw frames to `stream_p`.

Comment: I need to keep audio for the livestream. Did you try the `-fflags discardcorrupt`? I am still testing to see if it doesn't cause any problems with a longer stream, but it is working currently. It does bring up even more warnings though. I guess it is more so ignoring the issue rather than an actual fix lol.

Comment: I updated my post with a simpler solution using pytube and concat filter (without pipes). I don't know if the solution is relevant for you...

Comment: I ended up using your first program with the threading. I somehow fixed my original problem with the latency when I was messing around with your second solution. Removing the `-re` flag in the encoder command fixed it and doesn't require the the discardcorrupt flag. I also experimented with another similar project (ffplayout-engine) and found that even that project gets the corrupt packet when the pipes are swapped and their project works fine! Thanks again